# An exercise from Hilton-Stammbach: not clear the statement

Tags: modules, linear-transformations

In the book *A Course on Homological Algebra* by Hilton-Stammbach, the authors put the following question (Chapter I, Section 5).

> Develop a theorey of linear transformations $T:V\rightarrow V$ of finite dimensional vector space over $K$ by utilizing the fundamental theorem in the integral domain $K[T]$.

It is unclear to me what the "*Develop a theory*" stands for? In the section where this question appears, the main (fundamental) theorem of the section is that *sub-modules of a free module over p.i.d. are free.* Can one clarify the question a little?

Comment: With no other context I would assume the question is asking you to describe the classification of such linear transformations up to change of coordinates. This can be done by applying the structure theorem for f.g. modules over a PID to $K[T]$.

Comment: I'm positive Qiaochu got it right. $V$ becomes naturally a $K[x]$-module with the indeterminate $x$ acting via $T$, and the polynomial ring is a PID. This way of looking at a linear transformation is explored in bit more detail in for example Jacobson, *Basic Algebra I*.

Comment: It aims for the rational canoncial form which can be used to decide wether two matrices are similar. You can find the proof in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form It is also in Jacobson, Basic Algebra I, Section 3.10.